# Why is simple_form generating a non-existent route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, simple-form

I have...

**/config/routes.rb:**

```
Testivate::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :areas do
    resources :heuristics    
  end
end
```

**/app/models/heuristic.rb:**

```
class Heuristic < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :area_id
  belongs_to :area
end
```

**/app/models/area.rb:**

```
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :heuristics
end
```

**/app/controllers/heuristics_controller.rb:**

```
class HeuristicsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @area = Area.find(params[:area_id])
    @heuristic = @area.heuristics.build
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @heuristic }
    end
  end
end
```

**/app/views/heuristics/new.html.haml:**

```
%h1 New heuristic
= render 'form'
= link_to 'Back', area_heuristics_path(@area)
```

**/app/views/heuristics/_form.html.haml:**

```
= simple_form_for @heuristic do |f|
  = f.input :foo
  = f.button :submit
```

At no point do I explicitly call `heuristics_path`, as this of course does not exist.

Why then am I getting the following error at `http://localhost:3000/areas/1/heuristics/new`?

```
NoMethodError in Heuristics#new
Showing /Users/steven/Dropbox/testivate/app/views/heuristics/_form.html.haml where line #1 raised:
undefined method `heuristics_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fea3b2ac1a0>:0x007fea3d027608>
Extracted source (around line #1):
1: = simple_form_for @heuristic do |f|
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read more about generating urls for nested resources here - http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects

```
simple_form_for [@area, @heuristic] do |f|
```

I think it's better than `url` option.

Comment: Yep that worked thanks and was cleaner. Will read the Edge Guide now.

Answer (score 3):

You are used nested routes, so the path will not like as single resources. You can run `rake routes` to check your path of heuristic resources.

Try change:

```
simple_form_for @heuristic do |f|
```

To:

```
simple_form_for @heuristic, url: area_heuristics_path do |f|
```

Comment: as I said, you used nested routes, so now your path for create new heuristic is not heuristics_path, it has prefix `area`. You can check paths created by run `rake routes`, it will show all your path.

Comment: Indeed, I knew from the start that there is no heuristics_path, but I can't find this configuration option for simple_path(see http://rubydoc.info/search/github/plataformatec/simple_form/master?q=url). Obviously the code you have supplied is correct because it worked, but I'm not sure why given that I was already using a nested URL (http://localhost:3000/areas/1/heuristics/new) and I was not explicitly calling heuristics_path anywhere as far as I could tell. Is there more you can say by way of explanation?

Comment: now if you want linking to new heuristic, it is new_area_heuristic_path. You can read more here [routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: Thanks, I experienced a very similar and this answer solved my problem. Difference: my nested resource had an 'as:' option to change the name of the helper. (Rails 4.1, Simple Form 3.1.0.rc2)